# (Android) How to change what opens first in app

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, gallery, manifest

I have a gallery app that defaults to the camera roll. I want the app to default to the Albums section when opened instead of having to use the slide menu.

Is this something I would Modify in the manifest? Or could I make an entry with anycut?

Comment: Is this an app that you developed, or are you referencing the stock gallery app on your device?

Comment: Both actually. This is mainly just a learning experience in that I'm trying to create a simple Gallery app by combining features from various galleries and adding my own.

Answer (score 1):

If by Albums section you mean Albums activity then you can change which activity opens first in your manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityYouWantToLaunchFirst"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Okay I've tried using the activity I thought was the Albums activity but the app failed to open. How can I be sure the activity I'm using is the correct one? Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Log the Activity's name in `onStart()` of each Activity in your app. use the app then check the logcat for the Activity you want.

Answer (score 1):

what i understood is that you want to chose which activity appears first when launching your application, in that case go to your manifest file and look for the activity which has this intent filter

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

where this is the first activity to launch, therefore change the android:name to whatever activity you want to appear first.

So assuming you have 2 activities and you want one of them to launch first then you would just swap names between activity having intent filter i mentioned above and the other one without intent filter mentioned, that is if you have not added extra code inside one of the activities.

Answer (score 0):

always open splash screen and do some operation and store data in sharedpreference. and check if value equal 1 then set A activity , if value is 2 then set B activity ... so like this